# What is a Gap Shot?

Tags: zumas-revenge

In Zuma's Revenge, you can get bonus points for making gap shots in a level. I have never done any, because I honestly do not understand what they are.

What is a gap shot? How do I do one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's when you shoot your marble BETWEEN two other marbles into the second row through the hole you made by lining up the colors.  You can only make the hole as long as you don't trigger a combo, as the combo causes the balls to slam back together.

Here's an example from the [Zuma's Revenge review](http://www.smallgamereview.com/smallgamereview_33.html) on smallgamereview.com. The player is about to shoot the red ball through the gap between blue and yellow for a gap shot. (You can also hit a double gap shot by shooting through two holes that are lined up.)

[image: image of gap shot]

Comment: Ah, so if I have only one row of marbles, it is impossible to make a gap shot?

Comment: @AshleyNunn Yes, it is impossible.